# Returning undefined when i tried to return db search result

Tags: javascript, electron, undefined, nedb

I creating electron app with neDB.

I want to create function:

```
const getAllHosts = (db) => {
    db.find({}, (err, hosts) => {
        return hosts
    })
}
```

But when i call this function, it return undefined, i tried to change it to `async`, but it not helped me.

Comment: `return hosts;` does not return the value to `getAllHosts`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're not returning anything from `getAllHosts`.

Try like this

```
const getAllHosts = (db) => {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     db.find({}, (err, hosts) => {
       if (err) return reject(err);
       resolve(hosts)
     })
  })
}

getAllHosts().then(hosts => console.log(hosts)).catch(err => console.err(err))
```

If your `db.find` already returns a promise, you can try something like this

```
const getAllHosts = async (db) => {
   try {
     const hosts = await db.find({})
     return hosts
   } catch(err) {
     throw err
   }
}

getAllHosts().then(hosts => console.log(hosts)).catch(err => console.err(err))
```

Comment: Or just `return await db.find({})`

Comment: That(`return db.find({})`) works, but you might need to handle errors whenever you calls it.